# SQL Server 2016 transpose certain data from row to column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am using a code to transpose specific data from rows to columns, when I use it in a small sample it works fine but then for the original sample of approximately 3.4 millions of rows it replies  this:

> Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot create a row of size 36912 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

(more details here:) [SQL Server 2008: Rows into columns in a dynamic way "HELP" with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269193/sql-server-2008-rows-into-columns-in-a-dynamic-way-help-with-the-code)

Code:

```
        declare @sql nvarchar(max);
        declare @fields nvarchar(max);

        set @fields=stuff((select ',['+column0+']'
               from dll_ptbv
               where column0 not in ('Code','Mnemonic')
               group by column0
               order by case when column0='Name' then 0 else 3 end
               ,column0
               for xml path('')
              ,type
               ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
               ,1 ,1 ,'');
      set@sql='select'+@fields 
         + 'from (select column0
                        ,column1
                        ,sum(rn1*rn2) over(order by rn2) as rn
                 from (select column0
                             ,column1
                             ,case when column0=''Name'' then 1 else 0 end as rn1
                             ,row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rn2
                     from dll_ptbv
                     ) as a
                ) as a
     pivot (max(column1) for column0 in ('+@fields+')) as p
     order by [Name]';
      execute sp_executesql @sql;
```

[image: Small sample results]

Comment: Are you trying to insert your results anywhere?

Comment: what do you mean by "insert ..anywhere?"

Comment: I mean are you inserting them into a table (temporary or permanent). This error is usually caused by trying to insert a row with IN_ROW_DATA is over 8kb

Comment: I am inserting it into a permanent one !

Comment: Then that is your problem, you have too many columns. Why would you want to denormalise your data in this way?

Comment: there should be 2611 columns  (from 29/12/2006 to 30/12/2006 -> daily data) is that too much ? I am doing this because when I import the data from Datastream (financial platform) it's imputed in 2 columns (Date and Values) and it would be impossible to process the data in that way.. because I will need to calculate a z-score and therefore I need it to be in a nice format..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Solution is not to use `order by` in your script.

Your issue is that you are trying to order a row with more than 8060 bytes of data ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)).

> Bytes per GROUP BY, ORDER BY      8,060

I have written some code to trial your thing.

As expected it works when we comment out `order by [Name]`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dll_ptbv

CREATE TABLE dll_ptbv(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,column0 NVARCHAR(MAX)
,column1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )

INSERT dll_ptbv VALUES ('Name', 'Very very company name')

-- generate dates and insert into table
DECLARE @start DATE, @end DATE;
SELECT @start = '20000101', @end = '20021201';

;WITH n AS 
(
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, @end) + 1) 
n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects

)
INSERT dll_ptbv
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, @start), ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT))
FROM n;

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dll_ptbv

 DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
 DECLARE @fields nvarchar(max);

    set @fields=stuff((select ', ['+column0+']'
           from dll_ptbv
           where column0 not in ('Code','Mnemonic')
           group by column0
           order by case when column0='Name' then 0 else 3 end
           ,column0
           for xml path('')
          ,type
           ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
           ,1 ,1 ,'');
  SET @sql='select'+@fields 
     + 'from (select column0
                    ,column1
                    ,sum(rn1*rn2) over(order by rn2) as rn
             from (select column0
                         ,column1
                         ,case when column0=''Name'' then 1 else 0 end as rn1
                         ,row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rn2
                 from dll_ptbv
                 ) as a
            ) as a
 pivot (max(column1) for column0 in ('+@fields+')) as p
 --order by [Name]
 ';

  PRINT @SQL
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```